Browser not saving cookie for AWS custom domain attached to Elastic BeanStalk instance
I'm having issues when I'm trying to save the login access token on the browser's cookies when I'm using my custom domain attached to my AWS Elastic BeanStalk instance. If I'm accessing it using the instance's domain (my-custom-domain.aws-region.elasticbeanstalk.com) it's working fine, but if I try to access it from the custom domain attached to it, it's not saving it. At this point both domains (instance and custom domain) are not secured (I'm using HTTP).
When sending the cookie, I'm using the following logic on the /login endpoint on the Spring Boot backend:
ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from("accessToken", logInDTO.getJwt())
                .httpOnly(true)
                .secure(false)
                .path("/")
                .maxAge(1800)
                .build();

HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, cookie.toString());

Also my CORS configuration looks like this:
CorsConfiguration ccfg = new CorsConfiguration();

ccfg.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000", "http://127.0.0.1:3000", "http://www.my-custom-domain.com"));
ccfg.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
ccfg.setAllowCredentials(true);
ccfg.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
ccfg.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));

On the frontend I'm using the credentials: 'include' read-only property on each request I make (including the login one).
The values on the response header when I'm doing the /login request are the following:

accessToken=token-value; Path=/; Max-Age=1800; Expires=Thu, 08 Aug
2024 08:08:04 GMT; HttpOnly

On AWS Route 53 I have a hosted zone for my-custom-domain.com where I have the following record:


record name: www.my-custom-domain.com
record type: A
routing: Simple
alias: Yes
Value/Route traffic to: my-custom-domain.aws-region.elasticbeanstalk.com


Since there are some workarounds to similar problems, I tried using both .sameSite("None") or .domain("www.my-custom-domain.com") when I'm creating the cookie object on the backend but it's still not working and even more, using .sameSite("None") prevents saving the cookie even in the Elastic BeanStalk's instance domain which is working so far.

What value(s) are in the Set-Cookie HTTP response header from your server when the client visits your custom domain?

You need to look in your browser's network tab (in the browser's developer tools), at the response headers sent from your server that has the cookie in it, to see if it is actually being sent when you are using the custom domain, and what values the cookie has that may be causing this issue. That would be the most important piece of debugging details you need to include in your question.

you won't be able to set a cookie from cross-domain unless you specify SameSite=None in a cookie. And you won't be able to do that without setting cookie as secure which you can't on localhost since secure only works with https. Generally either have both frontend and backend on localhost OR both deployed, a mixup doesnt work. For more info see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

I just added the values of the Set-Cookie response headers from the /login request from my custom domain in the question. One interesting fact, if I'm using Mozilla it seems that it's working, as I can see the Cookie headers set in the request I'm doing right after the login, although if I check the Cookies tab from the Storage I cannot see it there. However, in Google Chrome it is saved in the Cookies insde Storage, but it's not set as the Cookie header in the following request.

@JAsgarov I can use both sameSite("None") and secure(true) on localhost and it works.

U mean when both are deployed on localhost or only front end? Cause both on localhost is expected to work. Actually reading the documentation (link from above) it says that secure insists on https except for localhost so I guess that explains it

@JAsgarov I was meaning when using the frontend on localhost:3000 and the backend on localhost:8080. I assume using sameSite("None") with secure(true)  on a HTTPS domain should work. Then the question would be, is it ok if I make HTTPS the custom domain and let the Elastic BeanStalk's instance domain as it is? I'm asking it since I need to generate a certificate in order to use HTTPS and I need to know which domain to use for that.

I would assume it would work since the communication to backend is https as long as there is a certificate
